# Prove that cross product is associative iff a and b are proportional

Tags: vectors, cross-product

The question states:

Suppose $ a,b \in \Bbb R^3$. Show that

$$ 
(a \times a) \times b = a \times (a \times b)
$$

if and only if $a$ and $b$ are proportional (i.e. one is a scalar multiple of the other).

If we assume that one is a scalar multiple of the other, than proving the equation is easy, using various properties such as $a \times a = 0$ and $a \times ka = k (a \times a).$ However, I couldn't really figure out how to deduce $a$ and $b$ are proportional if the above equation is true. I get that the left side of the equation is zero. From this, I deduced that

$$
a \times b = ka.
$$
However, I couldn't progress much further than this. Can anyone help?

Comment: Started to write this out as an answer, but we could also show this via contrapositives with counter-examples such as $(\vec{i} \times \vec{i}) \times \vec{j} = \vec{0} \times \vec{j} = \vec{0} \neq - \vec{j} = \vec{i} \times \vec{k} = \vec{i} \times (\vec{i} \times \vec{j})$

Answer (score 1):

As you've mentioned, we have $a\times (a\times b) = 0$. This occurs if and only if $a$ is parallel to $a\times b$ or if $a\times b = 0$. If $a\times b = 0$ then they're scalar multiples and we're done. The second case cannot happen: if $a$ and $b$ are not parallel then $a \times b$ is orthogonal to $a$, so $a\times (a\times b)$ is not $0$.

Comment: Thanks, but could you (further/in different words) explain why $a$ cannot be parallel to $a \times b$?

Comment: If two vectors are orthogonal, they are not parallel. In $\mathbb{R}^3$ two vectors are orthogonal if and only if the angle between them is $\pi/2$, and they are parallel if and only if the angle between them is $0$. (These angles, of course, are defined in $[0,\pi))$.